# DELETE FROM table WHERE UID = x AND CAT = y

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple table - 3 columns  ID | UID | CAT

I am trying to run a mysql delete to remove the rows where both UID= something AND CAT= something.  But it doesn't work.  How do I do this?

```
$uid = $_POST['UID'];
$cat = $_POST['CAT'];

mysql_query("DELETE FROM Categories WHERE UID = ".$uid." AND CAT=".$cat."");
```

Comment: Your script is prone to SQL-Injections. Be sure to properly sanitize your parameters. The best way to do this is using PDO or MySQLi and Preparent Statements.

Comment: Is ether or both of the columns (UID , CAT) a VARCHAR/CHAR column?

Comment: Have you checked that there are matching datasets by echoing the built query and PHPMyAdmin or something similar?

Comment: UID is INT and CAT is VARCHAR

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Categories WHERE UID = $uid AND CAT='$cat'");
```

Comment: Since uid is an integer, should it really be put inside ''?

Comment: No, if it is numeric then it doesn't need to be enclosed with quotes

Comment: Maybe you should edit your post then, because OP said column uid is of type integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$uid = $_POST['UID'];
$cat = $_POST['CAT'];

mysql_query("DELETE FROM Categories WHERE UID = ".$uid." AND CAT=".$cat."");
```

VARCHAR need to be escaped

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Categories WHERE UID = ".$uid." AND CAT='".$cat."'");
```

another hint use mysql_real_escape_string or another form of checking user input

```
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UID']);
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CAT']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an active database connection?  If not, you'll need to create one before calling `mysql_query()`.

Other than that, you may be forgetting single quotes in the query:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Categories WHERE UID = ".$uid." AND CAT=".$cat."");
```

Should be:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Categories WHERE UID = ".$uid." AND CAT='".$cat."'");
```

Assuming `CAT` is not a numeric column.

Comment: yes I have an a DB connection earlier in the script.  None of the suggestions have worked.  I can do it WHERE UID= but I can't do it when I try to do an AND.  UID is a INT and CAT is a VARCHAR.

Comment: @JamesAckerman: Did you add the single quotes to the query like I suggested?  Does the data in `$cat` also have single quotes in it?  If so, it will break the query.  Also, please note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.